# How to get value from attribute if it exist or else get it from other attribute in Xpath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes

I am new to XPath I have node which will have anyone of the attribute lets say..
lang and nolang....

here is my xml

```
<employee>
<name>krishana</name>
<speaks lang="kannada"></speaks>
</employee>

<employee>
<name>alien</name>
<speaks nolang="nolangauge"></speaks>
</employee>
```

I need to write Xpath which should IF node have lang get the value from lang....else if node have nolang get the value from nolang.

I am able to get from anyone of those like *//employee/speaks/@lang or *//employee/speaks/@nolang I need both condition in one xpath expression ...

Please help on this...

Comment: Do you mean `//employee/speaks/@*[name()=("lang", "nolang")]`?

Comment: @Andersson can you tell me in English the above XPath what it does ??

Comment: Returns the value of attribute with name `"lang"` or `"nolang"` from `speaks` node

Comment: @Andersson Great this is what I need BTW what does this name()= do ?? will it look for previous node ??

Comment: `name()` stands for the name of the node. In current case it's the name of attribute. Simply put, `/@*` means *return the value of any attribute* while predicate `[name()=("lang", "nolang")]` means *actually not any, but one that present in array `("lang", "nolang")`*

Comment: It should be noted that `name()=("lang", "nolang")` (comparing `name()` to a sequence) can only be used in XSLT 2.0 or greater.

Comment: It should also be noted that it's a convoluted way to write `//employee/speaks/(@lang, @nolang)]`. And that there is very little one can meaningfully do with such expression - esp. when OP speaks of "*get the value from*".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the context of `employee`, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(speaks/@lang | speaks/@nolang)[1]" />
```

to get the value of the first of the two attributes that exists.

Comment: I din't understood your expression will it get me the value from anyone of those attributes..lets say we have nolang so it will return nolanguage and if it has lang it will return eng ??

Comment: @GopiLal Yes. If this doesn't answer you question, then please add an explanation of what exactly do you need (and why) and what is the expected result in the given example.

Comment: As you didn't understand the expression, I will try to explain it. `(speaks/@lang | speaks/@nolang)` tries to create a collection of 2 values. The first is from `lang` attribute and the second from `nolang` attribute.
I deliberately wrote *tries* as non-existing values will not enter into this collection.
So if e.g. the current `employee` element has no `lang` attribute
but has `nolang`, then this collection will actually contain
**only one** item.
Now look at the final `[1]`. It states that from this just created
collection **only the first** element will be returned. Just as you want.